# Can I create automation testing in VS 2017 dotnet 4.7 using Selenium

Tags: visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, azure-automation

I am going to automate regression testing in Visual Studio 2017 dotnet 4.7 platform using Selenium webdriver. What language (testing) could be the best choice if someone can help. Also, what steps do I need to follow in terms of any other plugins etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Unfortunately your question invites opinion-based answers "What is the best..." etc _ Please visit SO Help Center and specifically thesection on 'Asking' for more guidelines on what not to ask >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: if you're using visual studio, the best way should use c#.